# find a file using find command only in particular directories even though that file is present in other directories

Tags: linux, bash, find

I have a file named `pqr.txt`    This file, is present in many of the subdirectories, but i want to find only the ones whose path is `../../whatever/whatever/pqr/pqr.txt`

I am doing this operation with find command using name option but how can i add this constarint that it has to find `pqr.txt` only in `pqr directories`?

Also i am passing name parameter as argument from command-line.

`find . -name pqr.txt`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to find only the `pqr.txt` that are in a directory named `pqr`,
you can use the `-path` option of `find`:

```
find . -path '*/pqr/pqr.txt'
```